# Change code editor variable highlighting colour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Within the SSMS Code Editor (for SQL Server 2012) I have this code written within the editor, that has a Dark theme applied.  When you click on a variable, SSMS highlights all the other occurrences of that variable in scope.  Notice that the variable highlighting colour is quite dark against the background.

[image: SSMS Dark Theme]

Within the **Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors** menu, can anyone tell me which is the correct `Display items` choice to edit this colour?  I've been through all of the ones that I can see that *roughly match* the same colour, but none actually effect the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variable colors share settings with table, object and other names. So you can change the text color using `Identifier`:

> [image]

Just note that it will also affect table names, column names etc.

> [image]

For the *highlighted* color of identifiers and variables, use `Selected Text`. The highlights will use a slightly muted version of that color.

And no, these are not my current settings, and I only kept them that way long enough to grab a screen shot...

Comment: Hi Aaron.  I was more referring to the highlighting that occurs when you click on a variable, and SSMS highlights all other occurrences of that variable in scope.  You're setting *does* work, but then SSMS loses the ability to highlight scope variables.  Is that expected behaviour?  BTW I read your blog yesterday on OUTPUT VS SELECT VS RETURN - excellent article!

Comment: @EvilDr Ok, so is the highlighted background color not just based on the `Selected Text` option? In 2014 I no longer get highlighting based on the variable selected. If you are using snippets then I would suggest trying `Code Snippet Field`. Others possibly worth trying: `Highlighted Reference`, `Template Parameter`, `Text`.

Comment: You nailed it!  Yes, its *based* on Selected Text, but shows a lighter shade of that respective colour.  Frustrating that it can't be referenced directly! Anyhow, I set the option to **Automatic** and it produces a fairly subtle (but easy-to-see) blue.  I consider that a success!  Thanks very much and keep up the excellent work!

Comment: @AaronBertrand, It's lame that text highlighting isn't available SSMS 2014.  Do you know if there's a way to enable this?