# Where's my text highlighting in SSMS 2014?

Tags: ssms

In visual studio I find it very helpful to find where a variable is being used by highlighting it and all occurrences of that var will appear highlighted as well.

Is there a way to enable this feature in Sql Server Management studio 2014 while viewing scripts?

Text highlighting is mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73911/change-code-editor-variable-highlighting-colour?newreg=ea873072773b4aac8d4de765cbc04591).

Thanks!

Comment: I've never had that work in any version of SSMS, even in Visual Studio itself. It might for C# or web based language files but SQL and PS1 files do not offer support for it that I have seen. You might find add-on or extension that covers it.

Comment: Yeah,I find myself copying and pasting between notepad++ just to see text highlighting makes.  Very annoying... any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: For having it higlighted, there is none. You simply use find and F3 key, only thing I use. Which I don't recall ever seeing the highlighting selected values supported in SSMS 2012. It is not something I need or care about having, may be why I never noticed.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server Management Studio ([SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) 2016 has this feature.  There is no real reason to user the older versions now as it's supposed to be backwards compatible, although there may be a bug or two (see below).

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>F</kbd> to see your keywords highlighted like this:

[image: SSMS 2016 highlighting]

Maybe a few bugs for SSMS 2016 on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback) ...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This feature is available with certain plugins, if I'm not mistaken.  I believe RedGate's "SQL Prompt" plugin has this.

My favorite from Visual Studio was "Go To Definition."  I miss that one a lot from my app dev days.

Comment: As do I, as do I :)

Comment: @MguerraTorres "Go To Definition" is kind of there.  In SSMS highlight any object name text in the query window and press Alt+F1.  Any text you highlighted is passed to `sp_help`.  Alter these in Tools > Options Keyboard > Query Shortcuts.  I always have `sp_helptext` on Ctrl+F1 and `select count(*) from ` on Ctrl+8.